# UIScrollView is not scrolling in UiView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

when I scroll on `UIScrollView` that not scrolling . Also I am setting scrollview's `contentSize`. 
When I show one other subView and after when I show my view , it's scrolling.

You can see what is problem on this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hql6t96uaytvpzg/IMG_2463.MOV) . How can I solve this problem?

myViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myViewController : UIViewController



@property(nonatomic,retain)UIView * rightTabView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIView * leftTabView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIView * middleTabView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIScrollView *myscrollview;

@end
```

myViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];



    //create Tab views and addSubview


     CGFloat barHeight=58;
    self.rightTabView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, barHeight+55,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height-barHeight-55)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.rightTabView];

    self.leftTabView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, barHeight+5,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height-barHeight-55)];
    self.leftTabView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.leftTabView];


    self.middleTabView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, barHeight+55,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height-barHeight-55)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.middleTabView];

    //add Subview to leftTabView
    myscrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,300, 340)];
    myscrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    myscrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    myscrollview.delegate = self;
    [self.leftTabView addSubview:myscrollview];

    myscrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your middleTabView is obscuring your leftTabView (which is the superview of your scrollview). Either bring the leftTabView to the top of the view hierarchy:

```
[self.leftTabView.superview bringSubViewToFront:self.leftTabView];
```

or disable user interactions or visibility of your middleTabView (or add the leftTabView last).